# Life cycle of business objects in a web application

Tags: web-deployment, lifecycle, business-logic

This is quite a general question regarding software design in a web application supposed to run on an intranet of a company. The basic design is simple: I have a backend (PHP) on a server, where a database (MySQL) is holding all data for the application. The application is used in a company and shall reflect employee related tasks. The frontend webpage (HTML, CSS) shows a UI for manipulating employee data etc.

A basic business object is here the employee, which is represented by a PHP class. When the frontend asks to show data for an employee, the query goes to the php class, which loads the employee data from database, instantiates an employee object and sends the employee data back to the client. Further queries from the client involve some logic that is done in the employee object, so I wanted to keep the just instantiated employee object in memory and use it again. I wanted to avoid the database access to load the employee data, instantiate object every time the client does a request.

So I created an object manager in PHP on server side which should store already instantiated business objects and provide them on demand or load objects required at the moment they are needed (lazy loading). But I realized that (of course) the server does not keep instances in memory between different http requests from the client, so my object manager does not work.
In a desktop application this would work, but not in a web application. Is this a bad approach for web application design? Is it normal that business objects are loaded and instantiated on every client request?

Another possibility is to describe and instantiate employee objects in javascript class and do this logic on the client side where objects can be kept in memory, isn't it? But I thought it is better to do business logic on the server to not stress the client to much.

Comment: I think this is probably more appropriate on http://programms.stackexchange.com. That said, here's my advice: state leads to bugs. Don't have persistent state between requests if you can avoid it. It's very normal to requery and rebuild everything on each request. If this leads to performance problems, you address them later on the in process, not before you confirm it's a problem.

Comment: Yeah this question might be more appropriate on a more general software design platform, but I am satisfied with the answer I just got here. Thx for advice. Your link is broken.

Comment: Oh, geeze. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is not restricted to the one correct answer, but I think it is kind of a best-practice-question. So I got two answers suggesting to go the common way and do logic on server side by instantiating business objects on every request. I don't think the answer is based on opinion but on expertise that has proven to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to avoid the database access to load the employee data, instantiate object every time the client does a request.

You are headed for a great deal of complexity if this is really a requirement in your environment.  I would benchmark the actual cost of just re-reading the data and judge if the added complexity is really needed.

You are trying to implement an object cache.  If you solve the issue of keeping the object in memory between HTTP requests (it can be done), you will soon discover questions of concurrency (multiple clients acting on objects that you have cached) and the issue of transactionality (changes to the object cache must be written to the database in a transactionally consistent manner, among other issues.

If you really need this functionality, look into existing object cache implementations.

Comment: I have not much experience in web dev, so I thought it is normal to try to cache the objects, but according to your answer not and I go with the basic case to requery database every time. Is it normal/better to implement business logic on the server side or should I go with business objects/ business logic on the client javascript side? I saw approaches where business objects are shared between client/server and available on both sides?!

Comment: It is almost always better to implement business logic on the server side, at least from a security perspective.  You should never trust the client, as you cannot be sure the client connecting to your server is the one you provided.  Pre-validating some business conditions on the client side is very helpful to the user (e.g. restrict input length or other input validation checks) but should also be validated on the server-side.

Comment: It's reasonable to cache things that are mostly read-only, such as a list of countries or states but it is fairly complex to cache business objects that are being processed by the app. Sometimes it is necessary and useful to do so, but always more complex so only take that approach if you have proven that you have to.